# Cov(a,bc) when Cov(a,b)=0, cov(a,c) not zero

Tags: covariance-matrix

Is there an expression for $\text{cov}(a,bc)$ in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$ separately.
More concretely, if $\text{cov}(a,b)=0$ and $\text{cov}(a,c)>0$, is $\text{cov}(a,bc)=0$?

Comment: To get some insight, think about simple situations.  *E.g.,*, what happens when $b$ is a constant?

Answer (score 1):

It can be any way, there is no rule. For example, these 3 variables

```
       a        b        c 
  -.5838    .6671   -.3564 
  1.6934   -.3139   -.7946 
   .0174  -1.0426   1.1525 
  -.1862   2.1805   -.2131 
   .3458  -1.3224   -.6581 
  -.5027   -.4888    .4293 
  -.3906    .2701  -1.3695 
   .2722    .0468    .4639 
  1.2383    .5269   1.9485 
 -1.9038   -.5237   -.6025
```

have correlations (a,b)=0, (a,c)=.3 (b,c)=0. Corr(a,b*c)=.314. But corr(a,(b-.7)*c)=-.004. Naturally, addition of a constant (-.7) to a variable did not change its correlations (shown earlier) or covariances. But it affected a correlation involving the product of that variable with another one.